# No provider for ConnectionBackend

Tags: angular

So recently I had to update to the latest version of Angular2, RC.6. The biggest breaking change seems to be the whole bootstrapping (by "introducing" ngModule).

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [HttpModule, BrowserModule, FormsModule],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
    providers: [FrameService, Http, { provide: $WINDOW,  useValue: window }],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
class AppModule {

}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

However after a lot of tears, sweat and pleading to all the deities I could come up with... I still remain with what is hopefully the last error in a series of many:

**No provider for ConnectionBackend!**

At this point I am tearing out the last strains of hair I have left as I am clueless at this point regarding the "what I am missing".

Kind regards!

Comment: Looks right. You shouldn't need `Http` in `providers` because it's already provided by `imports. [HttpModule]`.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

`Http` is redundant in

```ts
providers: [FrameService, Http, { provide: $WINDOW,  useValue: window }],
```

because `HttpModule` in

```ts
imports: [HttpModule, BrowserModule, FormsModule],
```

provides it already.

Comment: They are aware of this problem and are constantly improving. I assume that after Angular2 itself has stabilized, they will work even more on improving the developer experience with better errors and proper tool support like checking the templates for syntax errors and other issues, designers and other tools that make a developers life easier.

Answer (score 2):

In app.module.ts add:

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

And import module:

```
imports: [
    ...
    HttpModule
    ...
  ],
```

Answer (score -1):

I removed 'Http' from this import like this and it worked for me.
Also, BrowserModule must come before HttpModule in the modume imports.

Before:

```
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
```

After:

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

Comment: Define an example scenario from your suggested "some scenarios"... if not your answer is already provided by [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%c3%bcnter-z%c3%b6chbauer) and will likely be removed in the near future. We're here to learn and not to read the same information twice (read: rep hunt).